# th entailment of logic sentences

Tags: logic

> True or False: if $\alpha \vDash (\beta\land\gamma)$ then $\alpha \vDash \beta$ and $\alpha \vDash \gamma$.

Answer: true because for the and statement to be correct both $\beta$ and $\gamma$ would have to be the same.

> True or False: if $\alpha \vDash (\beta\lor\gamma)$ then $\alpha \vDash \beta$ or $\alpha \vDash \gamma$ (or both)

For this one I am unsure. any insight?

Comment: In the first, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ would not have to be the same.  Just taking any two distinct things provable from $\alpha$; these won't be the same by our choice, but $\alpha$ certainly proves their conjugation.  Do you have the Completeness Theorem at your disposal?

Answer (score 1):

The first one is indeed true, but not for the reason you give. For example, if we set $\alpha \equiv Q \land P$, $\beta\equiv P$, and $\gamma\equiv Q$ (where $P$ and $Q$ are propositional variables), then the premise becomes
$$ Q\land P \vDash P\land Q$$
which certainly is the case, even though $P$ and $Q$ are *not* the same.

Rather your argument should be that for if we have a valuation/interpretation that satisfies $\beta\land\gamma$, then by definition of $\vDash$ it also has to satisfy $\beta$ and $\gamma$ separately.

In the second question, consider what happens if we set $\alpha \equiv P \lor Q$, $\beta\equiv P$, and $\gamma\equiv Q$? Does the assumption hold? Does the purported conclusion?

Comment: yes it should hold as well then. if we have an interpetation that satisifes b V y then by definition it has to satisfy b or y, or can satisfy both. is my thinking sound?

Comment: @user251080: No. The question doesn't ask about a single interpretation. Find your definition of $\alpha\vDash\beta$ -- it speaks about _all_ interpretations that satisfy $\alpha$. So in order for the second claim to be true it must _either_ be the case that all interpretations that satisfy $\alpha$ also satisfy $\beta$, _or_ that all these interpretations also satisfy $\gamma$. It won't work that some of them satisfy $\beta$ and others satisfy $\gamma$.